# Programming language for multi-platform large software development?

Tags: c#, c++, c, user-interface

I have experience in C/C++ and C#, and I'm planning to create a large software with the help of my friends, which will also include a GUI. It will focus on computer security and analysis, something like penetration testing, risk management, etc. The point is that I want it to be multi-platform software. I want it especially to work in Windows, Linux and Mac OS X. The point is that I don't know which programming language and programming paradigms/tools to use for this purpose. I want to hear your suggestions, any suggestion is highly welcomed. I plan to do several large software developments in the next few years, therefore, I'm even highly willing to learn new programming languages or tools, which will be useful and ease my job.

Comment: I would stick to the language that you and your friends are most comfortable with, and look at LOTS of cross-platform code in that language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ with Qt is multiplatform as well. It contains nice GUI libraries and Qt-containers such QString, QMap which make you work easier.

EDIT:
Using QtCreator you can design your GUI by 'Drag and drop'.

Comment: I will definitely take a look at this! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use Mono to develop c# projects cross platform.

http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Mono is a software platform designed to allow developers to easily create cross platform applications. It is an open source implementation of Microsoft's .Net Framework based on the ECMA standards for C# and the Common Language Runtime. We feel that by embracing a successful, standardized software platform, we can lower the barriers to producing great applications for Linux.

Comment: That was the first thing that came to my mind, but as long as I know Mono doesn't support the latest features in C#, and the latest .NET version. I think an update is highly needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think Java is a good candidate for this. It works on all platforms where JVM is installed, it has many components you might use (GUI, security etc), and very easy syntax. Typically development in Java is much faster than in C++.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You might be fine with a Web App.

If your audience is developers, then you might consider Java, or you might consider a language for a common backend (e.g. C++) with either dependence on a common UI library or dependence on platform specific UI libraries. Even if your audience is for developers, you can lose people's interest if it does not have a native-feeling UI. So you have a bit of a decision to make to determine how important that native look and feel is versus the amount platform specific code you write -- that really can't be answered by us.

Comment: Native look and feel is the most important for me at the moment.

Comment: @erkant ok. you should check out some programs for each of (e.g. Java, Qt, and Native) on each OS and decide which looks good enough for your needs. for example, i can spot a Java program on my primary os quite quickly. your SLOC and testing can easily double if you go the native UI route. this can take a long time to learn because you must become proficient with numerous libs, langs, and toolsets. if you are looking to learn, this is your chance :)