# Choosing programming languages for multi platform data visualisation

Tags: c, user-interface

[I read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768233/programming-language-for-multi-platform-large-software-development)

I need that application is working on Windows, Linux and Mac.
App main task is to get data via USB com (probably emulated) port and visualise it. 
What programming languages to use?
For data reading I think that c or c++ would right choice?
What about displaying data to user? Basically must draw graph (like CPU usage in task manager, but two times faster). One think is to use SVG to visualise data.

What would be right tools/way to do that? Main option is to avoid users to install additional software (except that I can bundle with main application).

Comment: Did you see what happened to that question?

Comment: yes, I see. But how I can learn? Doing it wrong way or maybe ask to people who can something suggest (right way) ... ?

Comment: I understand your situation, but the problem is that for this type of question there is no absolutely right or wrong answer. It depends on numerous factors, and listing, explaining and arguing about these would be too exhausting here on SO. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows and Linux you can choose .Net/Mono. On Mac maybe again Mono. It is not ideal but for simple graphic will be easy for use (and fast development).